# Which PHP Framework is most closely cloned to ActiveRecord (RoR)

Tags: php, ruby, activerecord, frameworks

As the question says it all.

Which framework in PHP is most closely cloned to ActiveRecord (Ruby on Rail).

I have gone through many frameworks claiming to be based on ActiveRecord ideology but unfortunately none really come any close to ActiveRecord. Wny?

Are there any such frameworks that I have missed?

Comment: Are you looking only for an ActiveRecord implementation, or a full RoR framework in PHP.  Also what do you mean by "none really come any close to ActiveRecord".  What would you consider to be really close to ActiveRecord?

Comment: I have tried Yii which claims to be a sort of clone of RoR and its  ActiveRecord. But it falls flat on many grounds as compared to ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the most stable and up-to-date project resembling RoR is [PhpOnTrax](http://www.phpontrax.com/)

Comment: I this is the closest PHP can get to RoR and Active Record.

Thanks for this.

Comment: is this framework stable and has good support from community ?

Answer (score 7):

I think you're slightly confused. ActiveRecord itself isn't really a framework; Rails is the framework, ActiveRecord is the [object-relational mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (ORM, or database abstraction layer, if you prefer).

That said, [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) is probably the PHP framework with the most similarities to Rails, in general.

But either way, why not just *use* Rails? You won't be able to get anything like Rails on PHP.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a ORM package then [Propel](http://propel.phpdb.org/trac/) is quite nice.

PHP has a little bit of trouble implementing the Active Record pattern. Because of a shortcoming with its handling of static methods and inheritance you can't (easily) implement a `Person::findByPrimary(1)` style static method.

Instead most PHP ORM's use a Table Data Gateway pattern and have separate classes for table opperations `PersonHelper->findByPrimary(1);` and row actions `new Person()->save()`.

Answer (score 2):

It is worth nothing that since the release of PHP 5.3, late static binding has opened the doors to the kinds of reflection necessary to implement ActiveRecord on PHP!

Answer (score 1):

Take your framework of choice and use something like http://www.phpactiverecord.org/ or http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a project called php-activerecord (beta):
http://www.derivante.com/2009/05/19/php-activerecord-available-for-beta-testing/